# Update only selected Fields using entityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

When Running below code to update only selected fields the other fields are set to null,

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateStocksPrices(Stocks stocks) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE stocks set price=price+(?) WHERE id=(?)", Stocks.class);
        query.setParameter(1, stocks.getPrice());
        query.setParameter(2, stocks.getId());
        entityManager.merge(stocks);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
```

I'm using spring boot, how to update the fields that I want without setting other fields to null. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are executing the update using native query, you need not merge the entity. The following code should fix this.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateStocksPrices(Stocks stocks) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE stocks set price=:price WHERE id=:id");
        query.setParameter("price", stocks.getPrice());
        query.setParameter("id" stocks.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```